# How do I return all the possible outcomes of a 3x6 matrix in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix

Step one: I would like to return all possible outcomes of a 3x6 matrix where possible values is either 0 or 1.

For example:
Possibility one:

```
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0 
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
```

Possibility Two:

```
0 0 1
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
```

etc...

Step two: I would like to give each position a probability of the outcome being 1 or 0 and therefore be able to calculate the probability of the whole matrix outcome.

I've tried the following code just as a start but it doesn't work yet and I can't wrap my head properly around how it works:

```
int counter = 0;
String [][] actualOutcome = {{"0","0","0"}, {"0","0","0"}, {"0","0","0"}, {"0","0","0"}, {"0","0","0"}, {"0","0","0"}, {"0","0","0"}, {"0","0","0"}};
String[] possibleOutcomes = {"0","1"};
for(int rowOne = 0; rowOne < 6; rowOne++) {
    for(int rowTwo = 0; rowTwo < 3; rowTwo++) {
        for (int possibilitiesCounter = 0; possibilitiesCounter < possibleOutcomes.length; possibilitiesCounter++) {
            actualOutcome[rowOne][rowTwo] = possibleOutcomes[possibilitiesCounter];
            System.out.println("Possibility " + counter + ": \n" + actualOutcome[0][2] +  actualOutcome[0][1] +  actualOutcome[0][0] + "\n" +
                                                                   actualOutcome[1][2] +  actualOutcome[1][1] +  actualOutcome[1][0] + "\n" +
                                                                   actualOutcome[2][2] +  actualOutcome[2][1] +  actualOutcome[2][0]);
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your examples are 3x3 matrices  not 3x6. Is that intended?

Comment: You want to generate all matrix 3x6 having either 0 or 1 (means 2^18 = 262,144) ?

Comment: From your code it seems you want just count the number of distinct matrices , is this correct?

Comment: what does "the probability of the whole matrix outcome." mean in your step two? I guess the input will be 1.a matrix recording the probability of 0 and 1 in each position 2.an expected matrix. And the output should be the probability of generating that expected matrix? Then I think the answer is simply a series of multiplication.

Comment: @MrSmith42 No that wasn't intended. Thank you for pointing it out, while I was trying out I was trying out at the beginning with 3x3 and I got confused while doing the question. The goal is 3x6, I edited the question. Sorry!

Comment: @dariosicily Yes I want to get each distinct Matrix first and I then want to apply probabilities on each distinct matrix.

Comment: @lidlesseye I will add a probability for each position in the matrix to have a 1 instead of a 0, and using that I want to get the probability of the each distinct matrix as a whole

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding first part of the requirement you can try this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Scratch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double counter = Math.pow(2, 9) - 1;
        for (int i = 0; i <= counter; i++) {
            int[][] matrix = {
                    {(i & (1 << 2)) >> 2, (i & (1 << 1)) >> 1, i & 1},
                    {(i & (1 << 5)) >> 5, (i & (1 << 4)) >> 4, (i & (1 << 3)) >> 3},
                    {(i & (1 << 8)) >> 8, (i & (1 << 7)) >> 7, (i & (1 << 6)) >> 6},
            };
            printArray(matrix);
        }
    }

    private static void printArray(int[][] matrix) {
        System.out.println("==================");
        for (int[] row : matrix) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
        }
    }
}
```

This will give output like:

```
==================
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
==================
[0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
==================
[0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
==================
[0, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to have a counter starting from `0` and going till `511` that is `111111111` in the binary system and instead of putting and manipulating with matrix just work with the number.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 512; i++) {
        System.out.println("Possibility " + (i + 1) + ": ");
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            System.out.print((i & (1 << j)) >> j);
            if (j % 3 == 2) 
                System.out.println();
            else 
                System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

your matrix can bes displayed as a line of elements:

matrix

```
[a] [b] [c]
[f] [e] [d]
[g] [h] [i]
```

line-representation

```
[a] [b] [c] [d] [e] [f] [g] [h] [i]
```

this line representation, when each value is between [0...1] would be analog to a binary number with 9 digits, going from 0 to 2^9 (which would be 512).

if you want to know all numbers from 0..512 then COUNT from 0 to 512 and convert that number back into the matrix

implementation note

```
for(int i = 0; i < 512; i++){
    String asBinary = Integer.toBinaryString(i);
    int elementA = Integer.parseInt(asBiniary.charAt(0));
    int elementB = Integer.parseInt(asBiniary.charAt(1));
    ...
    int elementG = Integer.parseInt(asBiniary.charAt(8));
}
```

Comment: @user16320675 these were just implementation notes (implementation **hints**) - i expect the OP to do some actual work ^_^ I'm pretty sure Mr. O would like that

Comment: i'm 100% convienced that `...` will lead to compile errors *laugh*

Answer (score 1):

Here's yet another solution:

```
        int limit = (int)Math.pow(2, 3*3);
        System.out.println(limit);
        for (int counter = 0; counter < limit; ++counter) {
            int x = counter;
            for(int rowOne = 0; rowOne < 3; rowOne++) {
                for(int rowTwo = 0; rowTwo < 3; rowTwo++) {
                    actualOutcome[rowOne][rowTwo] = possibleOutcomes[x%2];
                    x /= 2;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Possibility " + counter + ": \n" + actualOutcome[0][2] +  actualOutcome[0][1] +  actualOutcome[0][0] + "\n" +
                                                                   actualOutcome[1][2] +  actualOutcome[1][1] +  actualOutcome[1][0] + "\n" +
                                                                   actualOutcome[2][2] +  actualOutcome[2][1] +  actualOutcome[2][0]);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly succinct, at least for Java anyway. The largest effort is in formatting the generated string into a rectangular matrix. We use the trick of iterating over numbers that are a power of 2 larger than we need - this ensures that `toBinaryString()` returns a `String` that's `m*n+1` long - we then strip off the high bit.

In terms of probability of a 1 occurring at a given position - over all patterns a 1 will occur `2^(m*n-1)` times in each position, so I don't know that this helps.

```
static void printMatrix(int m, int n)
{
    for(int i = 1<<(m*n); i < 1<<(m*n+1); i++)
        splitPrint(Integer.toBinaryString(i).substring(1), m, n);
}

static void splitPrint(String s, int m, int n)
{
    for(int j=0; j<m; j++) 
        System.out.println(String.join(" ", s.substring(j*n, (j+1)*n).split("")));
    System.out.println();       
}
```

Called via `printMatrix(6, 3);`

Output:

```
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0

<snip>

1 1 1
1 1 1
1 1 1
1 1 1
1 1 1
1 1 1
```